# How can I parse integers from a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, parsing

I need to retrieve out the nominator and denominator into two int type variables, from a string. It could be:
"1/-2", "4 /0", "-2/ 1234", or " 5"(in this case the denominator is 1);

There might be spaces between the integers and "/", no spaces inside a integer.
And there might be only one integer in the string and no "/".

Any ideas? Thanks.

Hi, I combined your guys' answers, and it works! Thanks!

s is the string

```java
s = s.trim();
String[] tokens = s.split("[ /]+");
int inputNumerator = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
int inputDenominator = 1;
if (tokens.length != 1)
    inputDenominator = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String[] parts = s.split(" */ *");
int num = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]),
    den = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

Comment: Basically implementing my suggestion. I'm not sure about `s.split(" */ *");` though, if you want to do it at once you might try regex.

Comment: I'm saying this might bug through use of wildcards and not do exactly what the OP wants. It's best to mention what the code does exactly and where problems can occur.

Comment: There's no wildcard, the `*` is a [Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star). The regex only consumes the `/` and any spaces before or after it.

Comment: Ah yes, confusing regex and bash, never a good idea XD. Yeah that should work, but please do add an explanation for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Separate the string using '/' as a delimiter, then remove all spaces.
After that use `Integer.parseInt();`
To remove spaces well, you can try and check for the last of the 1st string and the 1st char of the 2nd string, compare them to ' ', if match remove them.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because you don't suggest using String's trim() function to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: the trim function is essentially a loop that doesnt include lead/trail and might not always be appropriate. it's also generally slow, especially when we have a long string. i would recommend using substring for 1st and -= for 2nd.

Comment: but the reason is that the method should be chosen by OP. the main reason I suggested split(regex) is because it really is the most effective way in this case

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..,

```
StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(s, "/");   
int inputDenominator,inputNumerator;

if(st.hasMoreTokens()) 
{
String string1= st.nextToken();
string1=string1.trim();
inputNumerator = Integer.parseInt(string1);
}

if(st.hasMoreTokens()) 
{
String string2= st.nextToken();
string2=string2.trim();
inputDenominator = Integer.parseInt(string2);
} 
else{
inputDenominator=1; 
}
```